# Entity Framework Code First setting Isolation Level by query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, ef-code-first

Sometimes you need READ UNCOMMITTED or (NOLOCK) but only when you need a quick snapshot over some non-critical data.

There are many ways to set this but all methods apply to when the sql LINQ is being materialized.

However, in my app I need to run several queries in parallel. They are actually being passed to some third party controls. The controls are responsible to invoke the ToList() or ToArray() methods, while my app just generates the query expression.

Is there a way to instruct EF to generate some of the queries under a different isolation level?

**EDIT**

Perhaps something similar to [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) extension? I mean something that has late effect, when the third party control executes the query

Comment: Are you returning (passing) `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @IvanStoev IQueryable<T>

Comment: Methods like `AsNoTracking` and `Include` actually set properties on the underlying EF object that implements the `IQueryable`, so the settings are available when the query is executed. In other words, if you want to persistently affect the generated SQL query other than through the LINQ expression, we depend on the settings that happen to be available in the underlying implementation. And there are no settings for isolation level or locking. In short: the answer is no.